# Infinitescroll, packery and canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, infinite-scroll, packery

I'm trying to implement [infinite scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) and [packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co). 
I'm by no means much of a coder, but this is what I've been able to get to work:

```
var $container = $('#content');
$container.packery({
  // options
});

/* INFINITESCROLL */
$container.infinitescroll({
     //options
}, function( newElements ) {
  $(newElements).imagesLoaded( function() {
     $container.packery( 'appended', newElements ); 
});
```

problem is, I also want to use packetry.spaces in conjunction with the canvas to fill gaps between elements, like in this example: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/shleG

I don't have a deep understanding of the code, but I've been able to come up with a satisfactory result with what mostly amounts to copying and pasting [right here](http://cubetestalmond.tumblr.com/), which involves this line

```
var canvas = container.querySelector('canvas');
```

etc. but... I've only been able to get this to work when I initiate packery this way:

```
var $container = document.querySelector('#content');
var pckry = new Packery( $container, {
  // options
  itemSelector: '.brick',
  gutter: 5
});
```

and I've been unable to make infinitescroll working on the same "container" when initiating it with the querySelector.

so right now I have infinitescroll OR fill-gaps working with packery, but not both.

If there's a simple way of making it all work, I'd really really appreciate any heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d'oh... when using querySelector to initiate (if "initiate" is indeed the word) packery, you need to append it like this:

```
pckry.appended( newElements );
```

and that's it.